# unable to play rtsp throuth vlc plugin on IE11

Tags: vlc, rtsp

I created a sample web site through which i will be able to stream videos across my LAN.

I am using VLC (the latest version) .

But i am encountering issue in win10 IE11 ,as vlc plugin is not loading in this . I am using IE11 and my machine is Windows10 64 bit.

and my vlc activex plugin is enabled:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVmT7.png)

Is there any solution

the following is my code:

```
<embed
    type="application/x-vlc-plugin"
    pluginspage="http://www.videolan.org"
    wmode="opaque"
    id="vlc"
    width="640"
    height="480"
    target="my_rtsp_url"
/>
```

Comment: Don't use VLC web plugins, unmaintained and unsupported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this problem.
I installed the wrong version of vlc plugin, my browser is win32, but I used the win64 vlc.